# Run symfony action from console

Tags: symfony, console, action, bundle

I have two action in my symfony 2 controller. `CrawlerBundle:Index:index`, `CrawlerBundle:Index:update`. I need run index action from console. How can I? I think it starts with 
`php app\console ...`

Help me please.

Answer (score 2):

Move the stuff you do in those actions to [a service](http://symfony.com/doc/master/book/service_container.html) and call it from both your controller and [the custom command](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/console/console_command.html) you'll create.

Answer (score 0):

Use [PhaxBundle](https://github.com/alcalyn/phax-bundle).

By only declaring a controller as a service, you are able to call your actions with :

```
$ php app/console phax:action controller action -p param1:value1 -p param2:value2
```

There is an example with a cron to delete old comments:

```
$ php app/console phax:action comment deleteOldComments -p date:2013-06-05
Old comments have been deleted: 18
$
```